# Remove duplicate element from a stack

Tags: stack, duplicates

Suppose  I have a stack and its elements are [1,2,3,3,2,1,4,5,4,5] top pointer of stack points to element 1. Now i want to remove all the duplicate elements, so my final stack would be [1,2,3,4,5]. How can i do this thing, is there any algo for this operation. What is the minimum no of stacks are required for this operation.

Comment: Being a purist a real stack being FILO would not allow you to look ahead an see what is in the stack in order to remove it. Perhaps a simpler implementation would be to store a list of what has been processed so that you can ignore an item when you pop it if it has already been processed. I am making this comment without any real knowledge of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't check for duplicates as you consume the stack? Each time you pop off the value, check a list of used values. If it exists in the used list, pop again until you hit a distinct value. Add distinct value to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, u don't specified any language, so i will try give some steps to do this operation on some pseudo-language:

```
Stack FunctionName(Stack paramStack)
{
   Stack aux1 = param;
   Stack aux2;
   while (aux1.size() > 0)
   {
      StackElement eleAux = aux1.pop();
      if (NotExist(aux2,eleAux))
      {
         aux2.push(eleAux);
      }
    }
    while (aux2.size() > 0)
    {
       StackElement eleAux = aux2.pop();
       aux1.push(eleAux);
    }
  }
```

Supose Stack represents a data structure of stack (sorry for redundacy), and StackElement represents an element of stack. The "NotExist" functions only verify if some element dont exists on some stack.

Hope it help. ^^

Comment: Please specify the above pseudo-code either in C or Python language.

Comment: You can convert this to a needed language. If u are using C, i supose that you are using an array to represent a data scruture for a stack. I don't know Phyton.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @ColdHack travels the second stack on each element from the first stack which could be costly on big stack sizes. First thing that came to my mind is use a hash map and pop each value from the stack look it up it the map - if it is already there do nothing, if not put it in and set the key in hash map to the value from the stack and value in the hash map to the index in stack, then when done sort the hash map by the values and just put it in a stack. If the idea is not clear i can try to post some general code.